# Layout constraint start top don't work button disappears

Tags: java, android

I have this `activity_main.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/table_top"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"

        android:layout_width="355dp"
        android:layout_height="107dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="40dp">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/first_name_label"

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="First name:" />

            <EditText

                android:id="@+id/first_name_field"

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="number" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/last_name_label"

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Last name:" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/last_name_field"

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="number" />
        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/calculate_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="CALCULATE"
        android:textColor="#303030"
        app:backgroundTint="#CCCCCC"

        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"

        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/table_top"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/table_top"
        />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

It looks like this:

[image]

If I remove

```
 app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/table_top"     
 app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/table_top"
```

from the button, it looks like this:

[image]

I need to position the button beneath the table. Why the constraints didn't help? How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>Although I tend to agree that dodging the table layout is better for this use case</s> It's a good use case for table layout since the edit texts should be still aligned while the text views have different widths.

It's totally not right that the table layout is useless with constraints so you can still use table layout if you wish.

Make your constraints like the following layout (of course tweak the margins as you wish to get your desired UI):

```
  <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="MY BUTTON"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/table" />
        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/table"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:stretchColumns="1"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
            <TableRow>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="First Name:" />
                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Last Name:" />
                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

It should look like this:
[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Don't use Constraint Layout with Table Layout, the last one is useless with constraints.

Delete Table Layout and adapt your constraint fields

Answer (score 1):

You're constraining the start of the button to the end of the table, and your table is constrained to the end of the parent, which means your button is pushed outside of the screen. If you open the [layout inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5Pr1.png) you get a complete overview of the view hierarchy and you can see [where the button is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RcK55.png).

I'm assuming what you want is to have the button below the table and at the end of the screen, so change the button constraint to `end_toEndOf="@+id/table_top"`